# Word for a document to reflect upon an event

Tags: word-choice

So, we're having an event and have been tasked with creating a booklet (2/3 page PDF) to show categories, nominees and winners

Between us, we're sure there's one word that encapsulates this type of document.

`Overview` suggests something before. `Reflection` doesn't fit right.

> Hey, have you got a copy of the `{document}`

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "encapsulates this time of document"? Can you show us an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used?

Comment: Sorry, this "type" of document. It would be used to describe the document.

Comment: Awards booklet? Handout? Pamphlet?

Comment: @pee2pee Can you see comments in my answer & clarify your question, please?  Will this thing be handed out at the event, or will it be prepared afterwards?  Are the winners known to the audience in advance, or are they announced during the event (like the Oscars, Emmys, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

This thing is called a [program](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/program)

> a thin book or a piece of paper that gives information about a concert, play, sports game, etc.

Comment: I see that as something beforehand rather than after the event. Let's say you went to a football match and the day after you got presented with a book with the photos and stats of the day

Comment: Hmm, you have a point.  It's unclear from OP's question whether (a) the winners are known in advance, and (b) if this thing will be handed out at the time of the event or afterwards.

Comment: Doh, sorry, you are the OP.  So this thing you're making is going to be given out some time after the event is over?

Answer (score 0):

**memento**

> an object kept as a reminder or souvenir of a person or event.
>   "you can purchase a memento of your visit"

Google "define memento" : https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS562US563&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20memento

**Commemoration pamphlet**

[image]